# PHP how to set first value of array to string variable

Tags: php, arrays, string, variables

I am trying to get the first value of an array and set it to a variable that I can use as an int. I am coding in php and sqlServer as the Database(I had to use sql server)

I have tried implode, but I don't think that is the correct function to use.

```
$username = gotten from user input
$password = gotten from user input
$detail = Customer::getCustomerDetails(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => $password));
$customerProfile = Customer::getCustomerProfile(array(':detail' => $detail));
```

Customer::getCutomerDetails is a function that returns the customer number from a query from the Database. The queries works 100%
I want to save the first value of the $detail array's output and use it in the getCustomerProfile function to get a customer's profile

I am getting an 'Array to string conversion' error. I know this is because $detail is an array and the getCustomerProfile function expects a string. Please help

Comment: $detail[0] or $detail['username'] still not working dude ? Like this https://www.w3schools.com/php/phptryit.asp?filename=tryphp_array_num

Comment: Nope, tried that. It still in an array form

Comment: What does `Customer::getCustomerDetails()` return, show `var_dump($detail);`

Comment: It returns '74' I need to use that 74 in Customer::getCustomerProfile()

Comment: Sorry, did you want it returns as integer type ?

Comment: Yes, sorry my mistake. I want it to return it as an int

Comment: Maybe you can use the TypeCasting, like $customerProfile = Customer::getCustomerProfile((int)array(':detail' => $detail));

Answer (score 0):

Using the type casting.

the code maybe like this

```
 $customerProfile = Customer::getCustomerProfile(array(':detail' => (int)$detail['username']));
```

or

```
$customerProfile = Customer::getCustomerProfile(array(':detail' => (int)$detail[1]));
```

[image: example]

Comment: Bad approach, how to know what its current key of first array element?

Comment: This gives me the following error: PDOStatement::execute() expects parameter 1 to be array, int given. When I remove $detail from Customer::getCustomerProfile(array(':detail' => $detail)); and hardcode '74' in the place of $detail, it works perfectly.

Comment: must be $detail[0] or $detail['username']

Comment: I have tried that, it still gives me the array to string conversion error

Comment: try var_dump($detail). i want to know please

Comment: var_dump returns an answer of 'int(1)'